# CSS & HTML Positioning

Tags: css

I am trying to make a website, and it is vital that everything is positioned correctly. I have an element that I have that I want in a certain position on all devices. For example:

```
test {
  top: 63%;
  left: 43%;
}
```

The problem is, when I test my website on other browsers, and different screen sizes, the elements **position** goes crazy. Is there a way where I can set a position that will stay the same on every browser/screen size.

Thanks,

Tomothy

Comment: define "goes crazy".

Answer (score 0):

```
test {
  top: 63%;
  left: 43%;
position:absolute;
}
```

and in parent div position:relative;

so the test is set according to the parent div

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the below code..

```
.test{ position:absolute; top: /*your value*/; left: /*your value*/;}
```

before the parent container of test..

```
.parent-container{ position:relative;}
```

left and top css properties are not working properly without position.

Answer (score 0):

```
test { 
     position: absolute; 
     top: 63%; 
     left: 43%; 
   }
```

**Note :** you must define parent class of test is like..

```
test-parrent { 
      position: Relative; 
    }
```